# How to use remainder theorem if divisor is not in form (x-a)?

Tags: polynomials

I have learned that in the remainder theorem , the remainder of $f(x)/(x-a) = f(a)$
My question is how can we use the remainder theorem if the divisor is not in the form $(x-a)$? 
My question is only for divisors with degree 1 .

I have heard in some places that we find the root of the divisor but don't know if its true.
If it is true then please explain why ?

I am just a 9th grader so please explain in simple language .
I apologize if this question is too simple or just stupid but I couldn't find it's answer anywhere and it's a genuine doubt.

Comment: The simplest generalization is that the remainder when you divide $f(x)$ by $bx-c$, the remainder is $f(c/b)$. Same proof.  It is a good question! One can generalize to division by polynomials of degree $\gt 1$. Details are somewhat complicated. It would help if you made your question more specific.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, What do you mean "Same proof" ?

Comment: This was answered below by Alraxite.  The proof that when we divide by $x-a$ the remainder is $f(a)$ has the same structure, just a little simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , you guys really helped me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is essentially the same to the case where the divisor is $x-a$.

We can write, $f(x) = (bx-c)q(x)+r$, where $r$ has degree $0$.

Setting $x=\dfrac{c}b$, we get: $$f\left(\dfrac{c}b\right)=q\cdot(b\cdot\dfrac{c}b-c) + r = r.$$